# How can I automate a basic genetic distance matrix in R?

Tags: r, automation, genetic-algorithm, distance-matrix

I'm trying to create an algorithm that would produce a distance matrix from a dataframe. The idea is that the dataframe will contain three or more aligned genetic sequences and the algorithm will calculate the number of differences between each sequence and convert this into a dataframe. Hence, the input data would look something like this:

```
      taxon1 taxon2 taxon3
1      g      g      g
2      a      c      c
3      a      a      a
4      a      t      c
5      g      g      g
6      c      t      t
```

So far, I have the following code to calculate the difference between two sequences (taxon 1 and taxon 2):

```
distance1_2 <- 0

for (i in 1:length(taxon1)){
  if (taxon1[i] == taxon2[i]){
    distance1_2 <- distance1_2
  }
  else{
    distance1_2 <- distance1_2 + 1
  }
}
distance1_2
```

How can I automate this without manually repeating the same code for each individual taxon combination? The finished matrix should look something like this:

```
   t1 t2 t3
t1  0  4  5
t2  4  0  5
t3  5  5  0
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether it is the following you want:

```r
outer(df, df, Vectorize(\(x,y) sum(x != y)))

#>        taxon1 taxon2 taxon3
#> taxon1      0      3      3
#> taxon2      3      0      1
#> taxon3      3      1      0
```